# VueJS (Nuxt) error, when install new SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, nginx, vue.js, https, nuxt.js

I have application VueJs (Nuxt) and its admin panel on WordPress, communicate through the REST API, are located on the same domain, the admin panel is in a subfolder.
Now the domain has a self-signed certificate from LetsEncrypt, Certbot. Everything works fine, except that periodically, users displays a message that the certificate is unsafe.
Therefore, a paid COMODO certificate was purchased.

After its installation, Vue stops working with an error
`500 Server error. NuxtServerError. Unable to verify the first certificate`

In this case, the admin panel works correctly and shows the correct certificate data.

Surprisingly, if you deliberately enter a non-existent site address, the frontend error page 404 opens, which contains site navigation, after which you can fully use the site, navigate through the all pages before the first manual reload (eg ctrl + R).

What could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

Mistake is not chained ssl cert

```
$ cat www.example.com.crt bundle.crt > www.example.com.chained.crt
```